# Pair definition in Coq has type "(Set * Set)%type" while it is expected to have type "Type"

Tags: coq

I am reading Software Foundations(*) and have an issue with defining types in Coq: In the example below I tried to make 2 type definitions. `t1` is the list of naturals, and `t2` is a pair of naturals.

The first definition `t1` is accepted by Coq but definition `t2` is rejected with the error message:

> The term `(nat, nat)` has type `(Set * Set)%type` while it is expected to have type `Type`.

I don't quite understand what is wrong and what this message means. What is wrong with definition `t2`?

```
  Definition t1 : Type := list nat.
  Definition t2 : Type := pair nat nat.
```

(*) http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/Lists.html#lab58

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `pair` is the constructor, `prod` is the type.

```
Print prod.
Check prod.
Check @pair.

Definition t1 : Type := list nat.
Definition t2 : Type := prod nat nat.
Definition t2' : Type := (nat * nat)%type.
```

Comment: Pair is a data constructor and prod a type constructor?

Comment: Right. `pair x1 x2: prod t1 t2`, or using their notations, `(x1, x2): t1 * t2`.